# Alteon AD 3 configuration

Tags: networking, load-balancing, nortel

Cannot find a manual on this product, any start point to learn to use this load balancer will be appreciated since Nortel does not support this product anymore i couldn't find any information on their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software running on the Nortel Alteon load balancers is called WebOS. The AD3/180E load balancers run version 10.

The guide you want is called WebOS 10 Application Guide. Unfortunately Nortel's site has a annoying system to prevent direct linking to documents, but the first two links from [this search](http://search.nortel.com/go/query.jsp?Submit.x=1&Submit.y=1&inthe=0&locale=en-US&nh=20&parId=9&ql=a&searchPath=&site=4&siteSection=7&status=&status_type=0&topics=&tx0=webos&tx1=&tx3=) will give you the guide and the command reference